# install4j install third party rpm

Tags: linux, centos, installation, rpm, install4j

I'm building an RPM installer with install4j. My installation contains few third party rpms that need to be installed, so after copying files to target directory, I want to run rpm -Uvh  to install it.
I tried to mention this command as a post-install script in Media --> installer options tab, however when installing my RPM getting warning

```
warning: waiting for transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock
```

and installation stuck. I believe that third party install process is blocked by currently running process that making dead-lock.

How can I overcome it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to install4j 7.0.3, the RPM archive media file type does not support dependencies.

Starting with the upcoming 7.0.4 release, you can configure dependencies on the "Installer options" step of the media wizard.

Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already supported.